# Change geom_point to a gradient filled shape/polygon

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygon, gradient

I am exploring how a specific index varies. The index is a measure of the ratio between the 10th percentile to 90th percentile on a log-transformed scale. To explore the index I've created this dataset:

```
dt = 
  data_frame(p10 = sample(seq(0.1,1.25,0.05), replace = TRUE, 10000),
             p90 = sample(seq(0.25,1.75,0.05), replace = TRUE, 10000)) %>% 
  filter(p90 > p10) %>%
  mutate(p10 = log(p10), p90 = log(p90)) %>%
  mutate(index = p10/p90) %>%
  filter(abs(index) < 10) %>%
  select(index, p10, p90)
dt
```

I plot the dataset to see how the index varies as the log-transformed percentiles vary.

```
dt %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = p10, y = p90)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = index)) +

  geom_abline(colour = "black", size = 0.75) +
  geom_hline(colour = "black", yintercept = 0, size = 0.75) +
  geom_vline(colour = "black", xintercept = 0, size = 0.75) +

  scale_colour_distiller(type = "div", palette = 1) + 

  coord_equal() +
  xlim(-2.5,0.75) +
  ylim(-2.5,0.75) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

This plot illustrates the ,point well for my personal use, however it is not ideal for presentation. I was hoping I could replace the dots with a polygon(s) with a gradient fill. However, figuring out how to do this is beyond my abilities. Further, I am not sure if it's actually possible to do. Would someone mind terribly pointing me in the right direction with this? It's much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the `interp` function to see if it serves your needs:

```
library(akima)

# interpolate data
dt.interp <- interp(x = dt$p10, y = dt$p90, z = dt$index,
                    duplicate = "mean",
                    nx = 100, ny = 100) # set nx / ny based on how fine your want the polygons to be

# convert results back to a data frame
dt.interp <- data.frame(
  p10 = rep(dt.interp$x, times = length(dt.interp$y)),
  p90 = rep(dt.interp$y, each = length(dt.interp$x)),
  index = as.vector(dt.interp$z)
)

# plot results, replacing geom_point with geom_tile & color scale with fill scale
dt.interp %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = p10, y = p90)) +      
  geom_tile(aes(fill = index)) +      
  geom_abline(colour = "black", size = 0.75) +
  geom_hline(colour = "black", yintercept = 0, size = 0.75) +
  geom_vline(colour = "black", xintercept = 0, size = 0.75) +      
  scale_fill_distiller(type = "div", palette = 1) +       
  coord_equal() +
  xlim(-2.5,0.75) +
  ylim(-2.5,0.75) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: plot]

(The grey region are NA values, because there were no points available for interpolation over there. You can run `na.omit()` on `df.interp` before plotting if you want to hide them, or assign them a different colour.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that converts points to polygons and sets the colours of each. I doubt it's exactly what you want but maybe it's a start.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
dt = 
  data_frame(p10 = sample(seq(0.1,1.25,0.05), replace = TRUE, 10000),
             p90 = sample(seq(0.25,1.75,0.05), replace = TRUE, 10000)) %>% 
  filter(p90 > p10) %>%
  mutate(p10 = log(p10), p90 = log(p90)) %>%
  mutate(index = p10/p90) %>%
  filter(abs(index) < 10) %>%
  select(index, p10, p90)

dt.points = dt
coordinates(dt.points) = ~p10 + p90
dt.polygons = gBuffer(dt.points, width = 0.01, byid = T)

dt.polygons$colour = cut(dt$index, breaks = 10, labels = F)

plot(dt.polygons, col=dt.polygons$colour)
```